# Rendering issues in Safari on macOS Ventura

Tags: safari, ventura

Has anyone else experienced rendering issues in Ventura for certain websites?  If I view [this page](https://zed.dev/docs/general/getting-started), the page is blank.  If I move my mouse around on it, elements bits and pieces of the elements appear.

It started happening for me macOS 13.01, but is still present in 13.1.  I notice that Mozilla and Chrome are fine, but [Orion](https://browser.kagi.com) has the same bug.  WebKit seems to be the common thing between Safari and Orion, but I haven't found any issues listed anywhere, for Safari, Orion, or WebKit.

Another weird fact is that, as soon as I focus on another window, all of the elements on the page render entirely, but as soon as I focus back on the page, they a disappear.

**Update**

I'm using a Studio Display and the issue seems to be there when Safari is using the entirety of the Studio Display.  As soon as I shrink the browser down to fit on the 16 inch display of my MacBook, it goes away.  When I move that shrunken version over to the Studio Display, the issue isn't there.  When I expand the width of the browser to fit the width of the Studio Display, the issue isn't there.  When I expand the height of the browser to fit the height of the Studio Display, the issue occurs.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any elements disappearing when I move my pointer around; though the little link icons that pop up don't do anything when I click on them. It looks like there's "a lot going on" in the code of that page, for little result.

Comment: @benwiggy If you click on one of the chain/link icons left to the section headings, a link to that section gets copied into the clipboard. And, to the OP: I can't reproduce the problem here (Ventura 13.1).

Comment: Hi @JosephTLyons, I do have the same problem. 

When I shrink the safari to a smaller window. There is no problem. 

In a bigger window, if I focus on Safari,  the content of the safari will disappear. If I do not focus on it, the content of safari will display again. Super weird.  

At the moment, do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same issue with both safari and Duckduckgo but no Firefox. Do you perchance have xcode installed? To me it seemed to happen just recently and coincidentally when I installed xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering issues are not always easy to tackle. Things you may want to try:

- remove any data cached for that site (Safari -> Settings -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data...)
- disable any Safari extensions (and, assuming it works, enable them one by one until it fails again)
- create a new user account on your Mac and access the site from there to have a point of reference

Comment: The first item didn't seem to fix the issue and I don't have any extensions.  Still need to try the third suggestion.  As a side note, I posted this on apple's forums and a few other users have indicated they experience the bug as well.  It seems like it's an issue that just a small group of macOS users are hitting, but it isn't just a bug that only I'm experiencing.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254474425?login=true&page=1

Comment: It's looking like this is a WebKit bug.